Download Edit/View form of SharePoint Online list as pdf
I have a SharePoint list which has custom edit/view forms. These custom forms are developed using SPFx form customizer. I have a requirement to provide an option to download the custom edit/view form as pdf. I am using SPFx react to do all the development.
Is there a way to download the custom form as pdf through SPfx or through power automate?

Meant to save the Form data in PDF or kind of Print PDF of the screen?

Yes, i want to save the form as pdf in a document library

It is possible with SPFx, below are the high-level steps:

Install jsPDF Library in your spfx solution. npm install jspdf --save

Write logic to generate the PDF content using your form data.

Here, you can generate PDF using 2 ways:

Generate html content to save in pdf
Use SPFx form co-ordinates to generate pdf content using html2canvas library.



You will find more details to generate pdf using SPFx here.
PDF generation is also possible with Power Automate flow and SPFx command bar extension as shown here.
